# MSK S3 sink not working with Field Partitioner

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, aws-msk, aws-msk-connect

I am using AWS MSK and msk connect. S3 sink connector is not working properly when I added io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.FieldPartitioner Note:without fieldPartitioner s3sink had worked. Other than this stack overflow Question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372884/kafka-s3-connect-value-is-not-struct-type-error) I was not able to find any resource

**Error**

```
ERROR [FieldPart-sink|task-0] Value is not Struct type. (io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.FieldPartitioner:81)

Caused by: io.confluent.connect.storage.errors.PartitionException: Error encoding partition.

ERROR [Sink-FieldPartition|task-0] WorkerSinkTask{id=Sink-FieldPartition-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. Error: Error encoding partition. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:612)
```

**MSK Connect Config**

```
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector
format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.avro.AvroFormat
flush.size=1
schema.compatibility=BACKWARD
tasks.max=2
topics=MSKTutorialTopic
storage.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage
topics.dir=mskTrials
s3.bucket.name=clickstream
s3.region=us-east-1

partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.FieldPartitioner
partition.field.name=name

value.converter.schemaAutoRegistrationEnabled=true
value.converter.registry.name=datalake-schema-registry
value.convertor.schemaName=MSKTutorialTopic-value
value.converter.avroRecordType=GENERIC_RECORD
value.converter.region=us-east-1
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
```

**Data Schema which is stored in glue schema registry**

```
{
  "namespace": "example.avro",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "UserData",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "favorite_number",
      "type": [
        "int",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "favourite_color",
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to partition by fields, your data needs actual fields.

`StringConverter` cannot parse data it consumes to add said fields. Use `AvroConverter` if you have Avro data in the topic. Also, Avro always has a schema, so remove the `schemas.enable` configuration